# How to limit the tap of a ball in Swift 3/SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3

So, I am creating a game where the player taps a random appearing ball in the amount of time allotted to them, and I want to limit the tapping at a certain number. If someone has some idea or a snippet code I'll be appreciated.

Here is a snippet:

```
 var tapCount = 0

 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){

  tapCount = tapCount + 1
    print(tapCount)

    if tapCount >= 10 {

        print("we made it")


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a counter that gets updated every time a touch is detected. For example:

```
var touchesThisRound : Int = 0;

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
   touchesThisRound+=1;
}
```

Then reset it every round.

Comment: If I change touchesThisRound += 10 that means user can only tap 10 times?

Comment: No, you need a variable like 'let maxTouches : Int = 10;' Then you may need an if statement in touchesBegan that only does something when touchesThisRound <= maxTouches. Then touchesBegan won't do anything when it detects more touches.

Comment: @Mike looks good, if by "we made it" you mean the user used all their touches!

Comment: yes. but when I write the code in my touches began and declare my variables. it doesnt do anything. All I want to do is stop the game when they tap for 10 times and then move on to the next level.

Comment: Then you need to write that logic in a function and then call that function in touchesBegan when touchesThisRound==10.

Answer (score 0):

Every ball should have some related entity (GKEntity). The entity could have a property called tapCount and you would increase this value for each tap. You could stop accepting taps when the tapCount reaches a limit.

Comment: Can you check out my updated question, If I did it right.

Comment: I think you need to read upon how to use GKEntity in combination with SKSpriteNode. If I have time today, I can try to write a little sample, but for now it's hard. Apple has some good samples. You could also read Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/EntityComponent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015172-CH6-SW1